# Convert output of atan to range -1, 1,-1

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to convert the output of an arctan function from a range of -PI,0,PI to -1,1,-1  -  in fact I've succeeded! But it's not very elegant:

```
angle  = Mathf.Atan2(y, x);
angle  = Mathf.Abs(angle);
angle /= Mathf.PI;
angle  = angle - 1f;
angle  = Mathf.Abs(angle);
angle *= 2f;
angle -= 1f;
```

So that does the job, but for the sake of my self-improvement, how could it be done more efficiently?

Thanks for looking & hope it's ok to post code here.

Comment: What do you mean by "-1,1,-1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $f(\theta)=1-2\frac {|\theta|}{\pi}$?  It takes $\theta$ ranging over $[-\pi,\pi]$ and folds it so both ends go to $-1$ and the middle goes to $1$.  That seems to be what you mean by $-1,1,-1$.

Answer (score 1):

I have only the very vaguest idea of what your code is saying, so this may not be new to you.

Let's assume that we're discussing the arctangent function on the extended real line, $[-\infty,\infty],$ where $\arctan(\pm\infty)=\pm\frac\pi2$. Then the absolute difference of $\arctan(\pm\infty)$ and $\arctan(0)$ is $\frac\pi 2$. For our adjusted version, we will require the absolute difference to be $2$, so this suggests that we scale our function by $\frac4\pi,$ giving us the intermediate function $$f_1(t)=\frac4\pi\arctan(t),$$ which satisfies the desired absolute difference property.

Now, $f_1(0)=0$ and $f_1(+\infty)=2=-(-2)=-f_1(-\infty),$ but we want our function values to be the same at $\pm\infty,$ and moreover, we want them to be negative. This suggests that we look at absolute values, which will preserve the absolute difference property from above, since $f_1(0)=0,$ and in particular, we have the intermediate function $$f_2(t)=-\left|\frac4\pi\arctan(t)\right|=-\frac4\pi\left|\arctan(t)\right|.$$

Finally, a simple shift gets us $$f(t)=-\frac4\pi\left|\arctan(t)\right|+1,$$ and it can be confirmed that $f(\pm\infty)=-1$ and $f(0)=1$, as desired.